# 'CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER' deployment error

Tags: deployment-api

We are deploying our metadata through ANT migration tool.there are flows which are calling apex class and some flows are getting called from process builder.we have test class for apex class and flows as well. During validation test classes are getting failed with error 'CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER'.

Note that all test classes are getting passed via 'Run All Tests' in Source Org. However during deployment validation exact same test classes are getting failed.

What is the root cause of thisissue?

Comment: new tests or new flows in metadata to be deployed?

Comment: are you deploying flow, process build and apex classes in single goal? It seems when apex class is getting executed, flow is not getting picked up

Answer (score 0):

I would request you to deploy in the below order,

1. Apex Class and Its Test Class
2. Flows
3. Process Builder